# Adding actionListeners to new JButtons that have been added to a JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hopefully the title explains my problem relatively well. I have a JToolBar, dateBar, and I want to add buttons to it like so:

```
    for (Day d : newCal.getDateList()) {
         dateBar.add(new JButton(d.toString()));            
    }
```

ie for every one of some object in a collection, add a new Button to the JToolBar. This works, except that I don't know how / if I can add an actionListener to the buttons so I can perform some computation once one of them is clicked.

Many thanks, hopefully I've been clear enough.

Ps - I should add that

```
 JButton button = new JButton(d.toString());
 button.addActionListener(this);
 dateBar.add(button);
```

Does not seem to work, even if the class the method is contained in implements actionListener also

Comment: Sorry, alex2410, where?

Comment: see [tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbutton+actionlistener) they have a lot of examples cooperation of `JButton` and `ActionListener`

Answer (score 1):

Add the actionListener in the same loop that you create the buttons.

Example:

```
        for (Day d : newCal.getDateList()) {
            JButton button = new JButton(d.toString());
            button.addActionListener(todo);
            dateBar.add(button);
        }
```

Alternatively you could pass an Action object to the button in the constructor.

```
       for (Day d : newCal.getDateList()) {
           dateBar.add(new JButton(new CalendarAction(d.toString()))));
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
for (Day d : newCal.getDateList()) {
     JButton button = new JButton(d.toString());
     button.addActionListener(this);
     dateBar.add(button);            
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("your button label"){
      // do your action
    }
}
```